# paperclip-dropbox evaluating nil.[] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, dropbox-api

Just trying out paperclip-dropbox but without much success.
Here what I have done.

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'paperclip'
gem "paperclip-dropbox"
```

Created an App on dropbox and followed these instructions: 
    https://github.com/janko-m/paperclip-dropbox

In my dropbox.yml

```
development:
    app_key: APP_KEY
    app_secret: APP_SECRET
    access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
    access_token_secret: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
    user_id: USER_ID

production:
    app_key: APP_KEY
    app_secret: APP_SECRET
    access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
    access_token_secret: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
    user_id: USER_ID
```

In my User model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :styles => {
      thumb: '100x100>',
      square: '200x200#',
      medium: '300x300>' }
```

In my view:

```
<%= image_tag @user_profile.avatar.url(:square), :size => '100x100' %>
```

Error message:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
```

Pointing at my image_tag line of code.

Note that paperclip worked real well using the local filesystem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in your User model for the image size, try to erase the symbol behind the size , like '100x100>' to '100x100' , '200x200#' to '200x200'